# Put command output into string

Tags: linux, string, bash

If I execute some command in a Linux shell, how can I store the output into a string (variable) so I can use it later? I need this for a Bash script, please help.

Answer (score 33):

```
str=$(command)
```

Answer (score 14):

`` result=`command` `` or `result=$(command)` both assign the output of `command` to the `result` variable.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to the other answers, you can use the command output directly in another command without assigning it to an intermediate variable. Example:

```sh
wget https://feeds.npr.org/510289/podcast.xml -O podcast_`date +%Y-%m-%d`.xml
```

is short for

```sh
TODAY=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
wget https://feeds.npr.org/510289/podcast.xml -O podcast_${TODAY}.xml
```

and today evaluates to

```sh
wget https://feeds.npr.org/510289/podcast.xml -O podcast_2020-11-29.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo "Output of my command:" $(command)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on how the proposed solution solves the problem and how it helps the OP.