# I want to write a shell script which will take mvn clean test command as input and when I run the script , it should run my maven project

Tags: java, shell, maven, selenium

I have created a maven project using Java and TestNG. I want to run my tests in a batch, so I put those in `testing.xml` file. I am able to run the `testing.xml` file from the command line successfully with the below command

```
mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=testng.xml
```

Now I want to write a shell script, which will take the above command as input, and when I run the `.sh` file, it should in turn run the `testing.xml` file.

Someone please suggest if it is possible or not, and how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Put command output into string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316822/put-command-output-into-string)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood clearly but do you want to make a .sh script that will run the `mvn clea test -Dsure …` command ?

Comment: Your ask is not very clear ?

Comment: @Martin , you got my point.

Comment: @SheetalMohanSharma Martin explained my question

Answer (score 1):

So you want to pass a command to a script, which then runs that command?
Put the following into your script file (named `yourscript.sh` for example):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Executing '$1' ...'
$1
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    echo 'command successfully executed'
else
    echo 'something went wrong :('
fi
```

Call your script like this: `./yourscript.sh 'mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=testng.xml'`

Your script should then run the command and inform you if it was successful or not.

Comment: What's the point of this kind of scripts ? It seems a bit useless as there isn't error handling or anything

Comment: Good question, I also wonder why someone would need this specific functionality. Maybe I just misunderstood OP ...

Comment: Hey guys, I found the solution. I just had to create a .sh file and add the following.                                                                                                       #!/bin/bash

cd /path/to/your/project/directory

mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=testng.xml                                       Thanks everyone for your help and support.